# C++ linking header/main error

Tags: c++

Hi I'm getting the error for each function I've tried "function not declared in this scope". I'm new to C++ and have tried to get my TA to resolve the issue but still haven't figured it out. Thank you for helping!

Here is my header file (circle.h):

```
#ifndef _CIRCLE_H_
#define _CIRCLE_H_

class circle
{
private:
    double x1;
    double x2;
    double y1;
    double y2;
protected:
    double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
public:
    double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
    double circumference(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
    double area(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
    void populate_classobj(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
};
#endif
```

Here is where I define my class functions (circle.cc):

```
#include <cmath>
#include "circle.h"
#define PI (4*atan(1))
using namespace std;

double circle::distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double dist;
    dist = sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2)+pow((y2-y1),2));
    return dist;
}

double circle::radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

double circle::area(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double circle_area = PI*(pow(radius(x1, y1, x2, y2),2));
    return circle_area;
}

double circle::circumference (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double circ = 2*PI*radius(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    return circ;
}

void circle::populate_classobj (double x_1, double y_1, double x_2, double y_2) {
    double x1 = x_1;
    double y1 = y_1;
    double x2 = x_2;
    double y2 = y_2;
}
```

Here is my main (main.cc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "circle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2;
    int switch_val;
    cout << "Enter x1 coordinate: ";
    cin >> x_1;
    cout << "Enter y1 coordinate: ";
    cin >> y_1;
    cout << "Enter x2 coordinate: ";
    cin >> x_2;
    cout << "Enter y2 coordinate: ";
    cin >> y_2;
    circle mycircle;
    mycircle.populate_classobj (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2);
    do{
        cout << "1 for radius, 2 for circumference, 3 for area, 4 for exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your desired computation: ";
        cin >> switch_val;
        switch(1) {
            case 1: cout << "Radius is: " <<endl;
                    cout << radius(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2);
                    break;
            case 2: cout << "Circumference is: " <<endl;
                    cout << circumference (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2);
                    break;
            case 3: cout << "Area is: " <<endl;
                    cout << area(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2);
                    break;
            case 4: cout << "Exiting program... "<< endl;
                    break;
            default: cout << "Invalid input please re-input value"<<endl;
                    break;
        }
    }while(switch_val != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it has something to do with my `#include` statements but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: A more specific title for your question would be nice for others who might have the same problem.

Comment: Does your main.cc contain the line `#include "circle.h"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `switch`, you do use a method of your class `circle`, like `radius`. Functions of classes, so-called methods, are only available to call using an existing instance of that class.

E.g.

```
circle mycircle;
double radius = mycircle.radius(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
```

will work.

But if the methods do not need any member variables of the class, you can declare it as `static`. Just write the word in front of the function in your header:

```
`static double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);`
```

Now you can call it without an instance of `circle`.

```
double radius = circle::radius(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
```

You only have to use the classes namespace, to let the compiler know where the function comes from.